# how to set zoom level dynamic in xamarin form map

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I want to set zoom level in map dynamically in `Xamarin Form Map` when its loading. I am trying to use the [Working with Maps](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/WorkingWithMaps/). The zoom level is working in the code on slider value change.

```
slider.ValueChanged += (sender, e) => {
            var zoomLevel = e.NewValue; // between 1 and 18
          var latlongdegrees = 360 / (Math.Pow(2, zoomLevel));
          // // Debug.WriteLine(zoomLevel + " -> " + latlongdegrees);
            if (map.VisibleRegion != null)
                map.MoveToRegion(new MapSpan(map.VisibleRegion.Center, latlongdegrees, latlongdegrees));
        };
```

but i want to remove the slider and set zoom level 16.71 when map load on device and do not want to use the slider. How can i do this

**Complete Code i used**

```
 map = new Map
        {
            //IsShowingUser = true,
            HeightRequest = 100,
            WidthRequest = 960,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            MapType=MapType.Street,

        };
       // map.MoveToRegion(new MapSpan(new Position(28.6587067, 77.14514),360,360));
        map.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(28.6587067, 77.14514), Distance.FromMiles(3)));
        var position = new Position(28.6587067, 77.14514);
        var pin = new Pin
        {
            Type = PinType.Place,
            Position = position,
            Label = "xx"
            //,
            //Address = "We are here"
        };
        map.Pins.Add(pin);
       // var latlongdegrees = 360 / (Math.Pow(2, 17.51));
        //if (map.VisibleRegion != null)
         //   map.MoveToRegion(new MapSpan(map.VisibleRegion.Center, latlongdegrees, latlongdegrees));

        // add the slider
        var slider = new Slider(16, 18, 1);
        slider.ValueChanged += (sender, e) => {
            var zoomLevel = e.NewValue; // between 1 and 18
          var latlongdegrees = 360 / (Math.Pow(2, zoomLevel));
          // // Debug.WriteLine(zoomLevel + " -> " + latlongdegrees);
            if (map.VisibleRegion != null)
                map.MoveToRegion(new MapSpan(map.VisibleRegion.Center, latlongdegrees, latlongdegrees));
        };


        // create map style buttons
        var street = new Button { Text = "Street" };
        var hybrid = new Button { Text = "Hybrid" };
        var satellite = new Button { Text = "Satellite" };
        street.Clicked += HandleClicked;
        hybrid.Clicked += HandleClicked;
        satellite.Clicked += HandleClicked;
        var segments = new StackLayout
        {
            Spacing = 30,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
            Children = { street, hybrid, satellite }
        };


        // put the page together
        var stack = new StackLayout { Spacing = 0 };
        stack.Children.Add(map);
        stack.Children.Add(slider);
        stack.Children.Add(segments);
        Content = stack;


        // for debugging output only
        map.PropertyChanged += (sender, e) => {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.PropertyName + " just changed!");
            if (e.PropertyName == "VisibleRegion" && map.VisibleRegion != null)
                CalculateBoundingCoordinates(map.VisibleRegion);
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

Well actually its quite simple :

- Assuming `MyMap` is the object reference of your map, you can use the MoveToRegion method to set zoom level:

  ```
  MyMap.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(
  new Position(39,-132), Distance.FromMiles(2))); // accepts position, distance
  ```
- This example above moves the map to a position and attempts to fit about two miles into the viewport or what you can do is you can create a 'span' by specifying 'latitude degrees' and 'longitude degrees' like this:

  ```
  new MapSpan(new Position(30.235, -97.733), 0.05, 0.05)
  ```
- When specifying 'latitude degrees' and 'longitude degrees' you can convert this to a simpler value (eg. a range between 1 and 18)

  ```
  var zoomLevel = 5; // pick a value between 1 and 18
  var latlongdeg = 360 / (Math.Pow(2, zoomLevel));
  map.MoveToRegion(new MapSpan (map.VisibleRegion.Center, latlongdeg, latlongdeg));
  ```
- **Note** that using the VisibleRegion.Center property will mean the map stays centred on the current location while the zoom level changes.

**Update:**

After you define the new map object you need to do it something like this:

```
map = new Map
    {
        //IsShowingUser = true,
        HeightRequest = 100,
        WidthRequest = 960,
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        MapType=MapType.Street,

    };
var zoomLevel = 16.71; // pick a value between 1 and 18
var latlongdeg = 360 / (Math.Pow(2, zoomLevel));
map.MoveToRegion(new MapSpan (map.VisibleRegion.Center, latlongdeg, latlongdeg));
```

Comment: i have updated my question can you please review and tell me where i can made this cahanges

Comment: i want to fix the zoom level 16.71 by default

Comment: thanks i used the same but when i checked the value of `map.VisibleRegion.Center` it is null when run the code

Comment: You will have to wait for the map to initialize for it check this for [more information](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/22493/maps-visibleregion-bounds)